# Making a Synology diskstation accessible via WLAN

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, synology

### tl;dr

What do I need to get a Synology DS214 locked in a cellar room to connect to my Wifi/ethernet/DSL router (to which the DS414 and the clients are connected via ethernet)?

#### The situation

I have a DS414 (connected to the client computers via a 10-port Netgear switch) which I would like to backup regularly to a DS214 that is locked in a cellar room. Pulling a cable down there would be an ordeal.
The DSL router (which is also hooked up to the switch) has support for 802.11 n/g/b enabled and working (connects a tablet, some IP cameras, and a BD-player).

The Diskstation software suggests you plug in a USB dongle and you magically have Wifi working, and the Synology site lists a hundred or so dongles that have been tested for compatibility. Most are "micro" or "ultra compact" dongles, but for example the TP-Link WN722N has a nice looking, big antenna. Since the signal has to go via 2 floors, a big antenna looks like a good idea.

The WN722N says "high gain" whereas the [WN8200ND](http://www.tp-link.com.de/products/details/?model=TL-WN8200ND#spec) looks very similar but says "high gain, high power", which sounds like ("big antenna and big sender" as opposed to "big antenna only"). Also, it has 2 antennas which are even bigger, and 300Mbit/s instead of 150MBit/s.
Two antennas are better than one, and 300 is bigger than 150, so I bought the WN8200ND and two supplemental 8dBi antennas, because you know, *bigger is aways better*.

***Of course that didn't work. Why did I expect it would.***

#### The quest

How do I get this working? Plugging the WN8200ND into the disk station does exactly nothing (tried both of them, and tried the AVM DSL router, too).

My first impulse was to plug it into a Windows 8.1 tablet. Maybe you need to configure it once initially, enter the SSID password, whatever. That'll do.
After 2 seconds of automatic driver install without user intervention, Windows told me that I could press the WPS button on the router if there is one. Doing so zzzzzzzzzap... worked. Not a single thing to configure, ready to go in 2 seconds. Just what I expected, really.
Pulling the plug and putting it into the Diskstation makes the "connect to a network" button in the wireless setup screen enabled, but no matter what I try, nothing will happen.

I am fine loading a kernel module by hand or editing a config script on the disk station if that is necessary (but if "nothing happens" is the only information that you have, that's somewhat futile).

I am fine spending another 20 currency on buying a Wifi router or a Wifi access point, provided that that won't mean I have another blinking box standing around which does nothing useful.

Maybe I just bought the wrong thingie, it could be as simple as that.

My expectation is that an access point is a "black box" with an ethernet connector that (after given the SSID password) simply forwards what comes in on the ethernet cable onto the wireless network and vice versa, and doesn't need a Windows computer with a fitting driver or such.
In other words, I'd simply plug the diskstation into the access point, and have it accessible from two floors above. Though I'm not sure if that expectation will be met.

So, where do I go from here?

Comment: An AP is going to look about the same as a wifi router, in terms of management interface, save that it has no routing features (wan config, port forwarding, firewalling, VPN, etc). You should be able to connect the AP on your windows host, configure it from windows to act as a wifi bridge to the DSL router, and then take it down to the cellar and plug the NAS into it. that way the NAS will see an ethernet connection, and your AP will bridge the gap between nodes with wifi. Or simpler answer, move the NAS in the basement up to the switch.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Well, the reason why the 2-bay NAS is locked in a cellar room behind a steel door is that I'd like it to keep a backup for the case when the whole place burns down. So, moving it upstairs won't do (though so far I'm indeed taking it upstairs every 3-4 days, plug an ethernet cable in, and run the backup. That's... sub optimal). Ideally, I'd like this to happen via `cron` every night, without me even thinking about it. So a typical $20 AP should do in your opinion? I'll try that, thank you :-)

Comment: Your design is flawed. What you really want is an 'offsite' backup. Synology DSM has the ability to backup to cloud. Suggest you investigate that.